# How to get the sum of two strings of numbers - C++

Tags: c++, string, sum, character, ascii

How do I get the sum of two strings that are numbers?
For example:

```
string num1 = "12";
string num2 = "4";

string sum = num1 + num2;
```

So `string sum` will equal `"16"`

How do I do this in c++?

I tried doing it with ascii characters but it does not work I cannot convert the string to an integer as well

Comment: I need to use strings because if the number is very large, let's say 10^40 + 3^47, it is past the limits of any integral data type

Comment: _"I  need to use strings because if the number is very large"_ That's something out of scope of the c++ standard facilities. You'll need to use a 3rd party library to accomplish that.

Comment: The bonehead simple way is take each character from right to left, convert them to a digit, add the digits, convert the sum back to a character and prepend the the character to the result string. Just like good ol' elementary school.

Comment: @user4581301 Add them up to which data type actually??

Comment: Pretty much sounds like homework task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add large integers using string, you can do something like this.

```
string doSum(string a, string b)
{
    if(a.size() < b.size())
        swap(a, b);

    int j = a.size()-1;
    for(int i=b.size()-1; i>=0; i--, j--)
        a[j]+=(b[i]-'0');

    for(int i=a.size()-1; i>0; i--)
    {
        if(a[i] > '9')
        {
            int d = a[i]-'0';
            a[i-1] = ((a[i-1]-'0') + d/10) + '0';
            a[i] = (d%10)+'0';
        }
    }
    if(a[0] > '9')
    {
        string k;
        k+=a[0];
        a[0] = ((a[0]-'0')%10)+'0';
        k[0] = ((k[0]-'0')/10)+'0';
        a = k+a;
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    string result = doSum("1234567890", "123789456123");
    cout << result << "\n";
}
```

Output

```
125024024013
```

Reference: [See the complete code at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ZMEGAh)

Comment: `string sum = ...` isn't the same as `cout << sum << "\n";`!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, but if this was visual basic you could have `dim sum`.

Comment: @user4581301 Who was ever talking about VB here?

Comment: thanks for pointing out, previously I didn't notice that. anyway, i have updated my answer.

Comment: Why do you swap a and b if the size of a is less than b ?

Comment: @RonthaDon I just want to check which string/number is actually larger so that i can iterate from the end to start of those two strings while adding the digits. try to add two large numbers with different number of digits in plain paper, hopefully you will understand!

Comment: @WasiAhmad how to do subtraction with string of length 200 and string ```s1``` and ```s2```, and it is given that s1 always +ve and  ```abs(s1) > abs(s2)``` as an integer.

Answer (score 4):

The flat answer is

```
string sum = std::to_string(std::stoi(num1) + std::stoi(num2));
```

See the [**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1159e2eb0121eba2).

---

The broader answer as for [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42357976/how-to-get-the-sum-of-two-strings-of-numbers-c/42358018#comment71866892_42357976) is:
You cannot use that technique to do math with *big integer* values.

That requires using an appropriate 3rd party library.

Comment: @Jonsmoke Yeah, I mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be written like this

```
    string addStrings(string num1, string num2) {
        string res="";
        int n=num1.size();
        int m=num2.size();
        int carry=0;
        int j;
        for(int i=n-1,j=m-1;i>=0 || j>=0;i--,
            j--){
            int a;
            if(i>=0){
                a=((int)(num1[i])-48);
            }
            else {
                a=0;
            }
            int b; 
            if(j>=0){
                b=((int)(num2[j])-48);
            }
            else{
                b=0;
            }
            cout<<num1[i]<<" "<<num2[i]<<endl;
            cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
            int sum=carry+a+b;
            int u=sum%10;
            res+=u;
            carry=sum/10;
        }
        res+=carry;
        cout<<res<<endl;
        reverse(res.begin(),res.end());
        return res;

    }
```

I added cout statements to check what's going on inside the function